# Call Martify Smart contract by cardano-cli

Tags: cardano-cli, smart-contract, cardano-address, decentralized-applications, backend

I call the martify smart contract by cardano-cli but I've seen the error Command failed: transaction build  Error: The following scripts have execution failures:
the script for transaction input 1 (in the order of the TxIds) failed with:
The redeemer pointer: RdmrPtr Spend 1 points to a Plutus script that does not exist.
The pointers that can be resolved are:

```hs
fromList [(RdmrPtr Spend 1,(Spending (TxIn (TxId {_unTxId = SafeHash "c502c6f0929e9eb7562097592a71d9e4aaae01033c7c5cb685c2103c9fee070c"}) (TxIx 1)),Nothing,ScriptHash "74d2a2a31173aad514c66551190f4ca4d6eedcdd71776a04ba263de5"))]
```

The command of building the transaction:

```bash
cardano-cli transaction build \
    --testnet-magic 1 \
    --tx-in c1ca2d6e65360e2acc78485ea93803e6119af1864872ff8cbdd6fcdf2044d7e5#0 \
    --tx-in-collateral c1ca2d6e65360e2acc78485ea93803e6119af1864872ff8cbdd6fcdf2044d7e5#0 \
    --tx-in c502c6f0929e9eb7562097592a71d9e4aaae01033c7c5cb685c2103c9fee070c#1 \
    --tx-in-script-file marketplace.plutus \
    --tx-in-datum-file datum.json \
    --tx-in-redeemer-file buy.json \
    --required-signer ./../../common/payment3.skey \
    --tx-out "$(cat ./../../common/payment3.addr) + 9982422778 + 1 d8375cb8ece93f752c57981c7978a6b3f9e06cee44c464dd3b7b7d2b.53706f7265734e46545f33" \
    --tx-out "$(cat script.addr) + 2000000" \
    --tx-out "$(cat ./../../common/payment4.addr) + 6000000" \
    --change-address $(cat ./../../common/payment3.addr) \
    --protocol-params-file testnet-protocol-parameters.json \
    --out-file buy.draft
```

Which: the payment3.addr is the buyer, the payment4.addr is the seller, and script.addr is the marketplace.

Comment: Two questions:
1) What's the datum-hash of datum.json ?
(output of cardano-cli transaction hash-script-data --script-data-file datum.json )

2) I assume this is the address on which your contract is: addr_test1wp6d9g4rz9e644g5cej4zxg0fjjddmkum4chw6syhgnrmegk8l8yj
(correct me if wrong)

Answer (score 1):

The PT5 error exhibit the validator func return the error code in Onchain.hs file. So I put wrong pkh code in datum. By set correct value on datum, and its work.

Here is the code I used for making transaction via cardano-cli:

```sh
# Hash the datum

cardano-cli transaction hash-script-data --script-data-file datum.json >> dhash

# PUT ON SALE

cardano-cli transaction build \
    --alonzo-era \
    --testnet-magic 1 \
    --tx-in 8b076a7b96a24af1aec65213a45636b1e45c6acfe62e368f29e6e5119e368091#1 \
    --tx-out "$(cat script.addr) + 1800000 lovelace + 1 33700cf3c3d4aa6c84d9fd8a506c6c5482e4249abe78e37829913caa.53706f7265734e46545f33" \
    --tx-out-datum-hash $(cat dhash) \
    --change-address addr_test1vqquurd5cglaqfnnusnsfy3w0u6r20hpa4hf9x75evnmhxgwcrdas \
    --protocol-params-file testnet-protocol-parameters.json \
    --out-file tx.02 

cardano-cli transaction sign \
    --tx-body-file tx.02 \
    --signing-key-file ./../../common/payment4.skey \
    --testnet-magic 1 \
    --out-file tx-2.02

cardano-cli transaction submit --tx-file tx-2.02 --testnet-magic 1

# BUY NFT

cardano-cli transaction build \
    --babbage-era \
    --testnet-magic 1 \
    --tx-in c1ca2d6e65360e2acc78485ea93803e6119af1864872ff8cbdd6fcdf2044d7e5#0 \
    --tx-in-collateral c1ca2d6e65360e2acc78485ea93803e6119af1864872ff8cbdd6fcdf2044d7e5#0 \
    --tx-in f2134f93278707a37a1ef03abac76e7fc38dd9796c1143f25953448efbd3fdca#1 \
    --tx-in-script-file marketplace.plutus \
    --tx-in-datum-file datum.json \
    --tx-in-redeemer-file buy.json \
    --tx-out "$(cat ./../../common/payment3.addr) + 9982422778 + 1 33700cf3c3d4aa6c84d9fd8a506c6c5482e4249abe78e37829913caa.53706f7265734e46545f33" \
    --tx-out "$(cat ./../../common/payment4.addr) + 6000000" \
    --required-signer ./../../common/payment3.skey \
    --change-address $(cat ./../../common/payment3.addr) \
    --protocol-params-file testnet-protocol-parameters.json \
    --out-file tx.04

cardano-cli transaction sign \
    --tx-body-file tx.04 \
    --signing-key-file ./../../common/payment3.skey \
    --testnet-magic 1 \
    --out-file tx-2.04

cardano-cli transaction submit --tx-file tx-2.04 --testnet-magic 1
```

Link to check on preprod cardanoscan: https://preprod.cardanoscan.io/address/6001ce0db4c23fd02673e42704922e7f34353ee1ed6e929bd4cb27bb99